# JavaScript prototypal inheritance confusion - what am I missing here?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I am struggling with a subject I previously thought I understood - prototypal inheritance in JavaScript.

I have a jsfiddle which outlines my problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/86sCZ/)

I have a base object and an inheriting implementation. I want the implementation to make changes to the base's properties, and for the base to access these updated properties.

Can anyone please point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` when you call `new cheeseBase()` is the object you're using as the prototype from inside "cheddar()", and **not** the instance of "cheddar".  Thus, the "saySomething()" function always says "all cheese" because it refers to the "captured" `this` from the constructor call.

If you change "saySomething()" to reference "this.favoriteCheese" in the "alert()" call, it says "cheddar" in the popup.

If you really want the subclass to be modifying the base object, alternatively, you could rearrange:

```
function cheesebase() {

    var that = this;

    this.favouriteCheese = "all cheese";

    this.setBaseCheese = function(chz) {
      that.favouriteCheese = chz;
    };

    this.saySomething = function() {
        alert("My favourite cheese is " + that.favouriteCheese);
    };
}

function cheddar() {

    var returnObject = Object.create(new cheesebase());

    returnObject.setBaseCheese("cheddar");

    returnObject.saySomethingElse = function() {
        alert("I like cheese");
    };

    return returnObject;
}
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your input. Is there a case where I will get into trouble with using `this` though? I know it changes based on context. If I am not using any closures will I be OK? - based on your original post without the `setCheeseBase` function

Comment: 2 tomfumb, you can get in trouble with callbacks from UI usually
$('#btn').click(obj.saySomething); will change this binding to context of the element clicked.

Comment: If you take my first suggestion (change "that" to "this" in "saySomething()"), then calls to the function will have `this` set to the *instance* of the class.  That means that each instance will have its own "favouriteCheese" property. That should work fine, but your question states that you **want** the instances to set the base class property.  I'm not sure why, because it seems like the cheeses would therefore be fighting against each other, and a cheese fight is a scary prospect :-)

Comment: @Pointy poor explanation on my part - I just meant I wanted cheesebase.saySomething to reference the updated property

Comment: @ValeraKolupaev thanks for the tip, fortunately I currently have no plans to wrap these calls in a callback

Comment: Ah, OK.  Well in that case you probably want the simpler change, and not the "setBaseCheese" function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you want to achieve is this: http://jsfiddle.net/yrU6y/1/

Anyway, in your original example you are not using the prototype of the base object. This would mean that everytime you created a new `cheesebase` you would redefine its functions, i.e. each `cheesebase` object would have its own functions instead of sharing the prototype (and using less memory).

Answer (score 1):

My best guess, that following code causes the problem.

```
var that = this;
```

My raw intuition (without reference to JS specification), it that prototype based inheritance is based on single instance of prototype object, without copying of this object.
So, `this` pointer inside `cheeseBase` points to prototype object, that should never change.

Descendants method and property binding, iterates over [this, this.prototype, this.prototype.prototype, ...] sequence while seeking method or property, where each prototype a meant to be immutable singleton object.

Given this, `cheeseBase` constructor have `this` pointing to actual prototype, stores this pointer inside `that` and creates closure around `that`, which is prototype object.

And, during execution of `cheeseBase` binding of `this` changes to actual object instance.

I guess something like this, can be found under this binding in JS spec.